# Redirect Subdirectory HTTP to Same Subdirectory HTTPS

Tags: http, redirect, https

I have googled for an hour about this, but none of the alternates are working for me.  My goal:

301 Redirect from http://www.domain.com/guides/men/ to https://www.domain.com/guides/men/

I have tried both of these solutions suggested on other pages and neither worked.  I keep seeing the http version of the page in both cases:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762859/htaccess-redirect-subfolder-to-https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(guides/men/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642877/redirect-only-one-folder-to-https-all-others-to-http
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} secure 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/guides/men/$1 [R=301,L]
```

At this point Im wondering if its my syntax, or placement within (a very large htaccess file - nearly 2,300 lines of redirects due to a recent major site migration).  I was putting it at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your first attempt, but you might have an error in .htaccess someplace. Check your httpd error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(guides/men/.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```